# Display Tiered Pricing on the Cart page

Tags: magento

If Im on this page:
http:///checkout/cart/

With products in my cart I would like to display the tiered pricing, the same that is shown on the item page, if available.

My attempt was add

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.tierprices" as="tierprices" template="catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml"/>
    </checkout_cart_index>
```

to my xml file and add

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('tierprices') ?>
```

to

```
\app\design\frontend\enterprise\<mytemplate>\template\checkout\cart\item\default.phtml
```

Doesn’t do anything - any further suggestions?

Comment: You need create new block class for this, you can't use `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Price` which is used on product view page because it looks for product in it's own varien object `product` property and registry. But on checkout page of course both these places are empty for evident reason.

Comment: please checkout this link 

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/magento-display-tiered-pricing-for-each-product-on-cart-page

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible to easily change layout. You need to modify item renderer and add tier price displaying manually. To fetch list of available tier prices you need to get price model. You can get it from product model

```
$product->getPriceModel()
```

or if don't have product model try the following code

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->priceFactory($productTypeId)
```

Quote item contains product type information.

When you have price model just call method getTierPrice() to get all tier prices as array.

```
$priceModel->getTierPrice()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the .phtml file and adding the $this->getTierPrices($_product);`//or`$this->getTierPrices($_item); if you simply want to display the tier prices of products.

Do note that the getTierPrices() only works when being on the product list or product view page, so you would need to copy the getTierPrices() method that can be found inside the List.php to your custom module.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you an idea what needs to be done.

layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="additional.product.info">
            <block type="LokeyCoding_Cart/TierPrice" name="additional.product.info.tierprice" />
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</version>
```

block file

```
<?php
class LokeyCoding_Cart_Block_TierPrice extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parent) {
            $item = $parent->getItem();
            if ($item instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item) {
                return $item->getProduct()->getTierPriceHtml();
            }
        }

        return '';
    }
}
```