# Display Tier Price on Cart page in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I display tier price on cart page in Magento?

I understand that the method getTierPriceHtml() only works on List and Detail page, so we cannot use that on cart page.

I'm editing /template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437066/display-tiered-pricing-on-the-cart-page

please checkout this link

Comment: I already checked that thread and other related threads as well. The solution given is not working, that is why I've opened a new question.

Comment: please checkout this link 

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1283/magento-display-tiered-pricing-for-each-product-on-cart-page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you want tier price in cart page also.I think this is useful for your functionality

you can directly use this code in ***checkout/cart/item/default.phtml:*** after the **$_item = $this->getItem(); (in line 28)....**

```
     **$tierPrice = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
'catalog/product_view',
'product.tierprices',
array(
    'product_id' => $_item->getProductId()
)
```

);**

```
**$tierPrice->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml');**

 **echo $tierPrice->getTierPriceHtml();**
```

> you can create your own style template that file also you can use it in place of catalog/product/view/tierprice.phml like catalog/product/view/tierprice1.phml